# iPhone: error in UIViewController interface declaration (expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'interface')

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have been working on this iPhone app for quite a while and everything has been working fine, but now all of the sudden, I am getting this error in a file I don't remember editing (nor do I remember editing anything relating to it, but it's possible.):

```
/Users/on_fire/BWOC 0.5/Classes/../BrowserViewController.h:29:
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'interface'
```

It's referring to the first line in this:

```
@interface BrowserViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{

UIWebView *webView;
NSString *urlString;
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;

}
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/ij8sNi7u) is the whole file (Pastebin).
The pastebin also has a link to a zip of my project if anyone want's to have a look at the whole thing.

I understand if you would rather not download a zip, so if you need any other files, just let me know and I will put them up separately as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This file looks fine. I suspect that some place where you've #imported this has something else goofy going on it. Look at the tops of files you #import this into and look for syntax errors.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find the zip at your link. For what it is worth, when I copy-and-paste the snippet above into a project, it compiles fine. I suspect the issue lies elsewhere in the form of a missing ; or "

Comment: Apparently it never updated the pastebin when I added it... I am updating it now.

Comment: Here is a link to the BrowserViewController.m file: http://pastebin.com/QLQAB547

Comment: What file was being compiled when this error was triggered?

Comment: I'm working through the code. See my notes in my repeatedly-edited answer.

Comment: @Shaggy The AppDelegate was being compiled, making it suspicious.

Comment: Can't wait for LLVM/Clang to become the default compiler so this kind of unhelpful error message from gcc is a thing of the past.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered or commented. While I have since moved to Titanium, since it doesn't constantly break for no apparent reason, I did look at everything mentioned. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you accidentally broke your AppDelegate. I've seen this type of error show up in a file that's parsed after the AppDelegate, with the parser seeing the start of a new interface file as an error because the AppDelegate isn't closed off yet.

**Edited to add**

I haven't found the problem yet, but do see some problems I figured I'd point out.

In BrowserViewController.m:

```
if( urlString == @"invite.html" )
```

won't work the way you want, I suspect. You likely want:

```
if( [urlString isEqualToString:@"invite.html"] )
```

And this method:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

has the webView argument that's the same name as your instance variable in the class. You should give it a different name here.

Same with:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

By changing those to **myWebView** throughout each of the delegate methods you're still referring to your own webView since it's being passed in.

**Edited to further add**

Unfortunately I don't see the error. I looked through all of the class files for anything suspicious but nothing pops out. My only suggestion is to consider the last change or two you made and look at the code there. Something completely innocuous can break the whole structure the compiler is expecting. Worst case, do you have a recent backup?

Comment: Edited to add fix for the ivar/delegate variable overlap.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I didn't have a backup, and since Titanium is finally at a point where it is able to do what we want to do, I just switched to that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quite similar situation.

This compile error came up on the @interface statement within an .h file. 
Alternatively it came on the preceding @class statement within the same .h file.

Apparently the error was thrown on the very first statement of that .h file that followed the usual #include directives.

It turned out that I happened to type an illegal character (in my case a 'd') at the beginning of the related .m file.

Like that:

```
//some comment
#include "something.h"

@interface myClass : itsSuperClass {

}

@end

d//some comment
#include "something.h"

@implementation myClass 

...
@end
```

Again, the error was thrown next to the @interface statement but it was caused by the single "d" character.

Hope that helps others.

Cheers
Hermann

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a zip link on the pastebin page, but is it possible that this file is being included in a non-.m file (ie, a straight C, instead of Objective-C, file)?

Comment: That would be my first guess, too.

Comment: Thanks, but it's only being included from BrowserViewController.m http://pastebin.com/QLQAB547

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't help but the header file doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem, the syntax is right. Maybe check in the m file

Comment: I think you are right about BrowserViewController.m, though I wasn't able to find anything. http://pastebin.com/QLQAB547

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing classes in your header file? If so, you might be missing a semi colon in the one of the header classes you are importing.

A tiny bit more detail here:

http://bencoffman.com/blog/2010/09/01/errorExpectedAsmOrAttributeBeforeInterface.aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding, but no, there's nothing other then UIKit being imported.